# Read from file while running a script during Vagrant provisioning?

Tags: bash, path, vagrant, vagrantfile

**What is the path of files being run during the vagrant provisioning phase?**

In the Vagrantfile, to place files in the right directories, I have a `config.vm.provision` that runs a shell script (example: `path:".provision/setup.sh').

The `setup.sh` file reads from another file in the same folder to run through the list of git repos that will have files placed on the client machine.

The script works fine testing outside of Vagrant but I am having a hard time finding where I should say it is located. Here is an example of the code causing a problem:

```
filename='./provision/gitrepos'
exec 4<$filename
echo Start
while read -u4 p ; do
  if [ ! -z "$p" ];
  then
    is_website $p
  else
    echo
    echo "This line '#$p' is blank"
    echo
   fi
   done
```

The problem appears to here:`filename='./provision/gitrepos'` 
While doing a `vagrant up` the file is no longer being seen as being on the host machine but somewhere else. But how do I find the location of a file that sits in the same directory as the setup.sh file in the first place?

I tried `filename='./gitrepos' but what seems the relative path does not work.

How do I find the location of these folders and files so I can access them during the provisioning phase?

Comment: To be clear, both the `setup.sh` and `gitrepos` files are in the same directory but I cannot figure out how to access the file if Vagrant is the one that runs the script.

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning script is executed from the `/tmp` folder - if you ssh into your VM and check the temp folder you will see something like `vagrant-shell` with your content of the script. However not all files from your directory are pushed to the `/tmp` folder.

If your gitrepos file is within your project directory it is by default shared under the `/vagrant` directory so you can read from there

If its not you need to created a specific [sync_folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) so you can read the file from within the VM